# I am able to upvote my comment

Tags: support, comments, votes

In [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45319/can-i-make-a-twitter-account-with-the-url/45320#45320), which was written under my account on Super User and ported to Web Applications, I was able to upvote two of my comments.

On other pages, I am not able to reproduce it, only in this page.

Logged in as:

[image: screen shot]

---

Upvoting comment:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Sorry about the mess :)

Answer (score 6):

You are up-voting an anonymous user with your username because you registered with Web Applications (2013-06-10 13:05:19Z) after the migration (2013-06-10 13:00:52Z).

Comments aren't given the same priority for user association during migration <sup>[[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68434/comments-by-op-on-migrated-question-become-anonymous/92991#92991)]</sup>